# Cant change STR to FLOAT to sum from Excel

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to bring in information from an excel file - which has a mix of integers and string values (both are numbers, however because of formatting issues not all come up as "numbers") I am trying to add them.

This is the code I wrote - and have tried to convert the str to float, however it looks like it is not working based on the error message.

```
Numbers1 = []
Numbers1Sum = 0
for i in range ("B2:B12"):
    float(i)
    print(i)
    Numbers1Sum = Numbers1Sum + i 
    Numbers1.append(sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value)
    print(Numbers1)
    print(Numbers1Sum)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 3, in 
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

This is the information on the excel file:
[data looking to process from excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBUJ8.png)

Comment: `range()` is built-in Python function that takes up to three integers as arguments. You're passing the string `"B2:B12"`.

Comment: What are you using to read the Excel document?  `openpyxl`, `xlrd`, a COM object?

Comment: I am using openpyxl to read the excel document. This is the data in the table, which is showing 2 columns, even though it looks like these are all numbers and the easy way is to add them, in the file some are "text", so I am trying to write something to factor this in:                                                                                   Test Qty
A 100
B 1000
C 200
D 2000
E 300
F 3000
G 400
H 4000
I 500
J 5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the conversion but in your range.

`range()` only accepts integers because it's that: a range of numbers.
If you want to find the sum of values in that column, I recommend you take the column and directly use the `sum()` function.

I cannot see your whole source code, so I'm going to make a few assumptions here.

Use the `pandas` module when handling datasets especially in the case of tables.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'filepath')
```

Then since you need the sum of values from B2:B12,

```
narrow = data.iloc[1,1:13]
narrow = narrow.astype('float')
print(sum(narrow.values))
```

This will return your desired number.

Comment: Thanks! the values I am trying to add are as follows - half of them are numbers and the other half are text in the file, so I am trying get towards covering them to numbers back in the excel file. however for now I am splitting out this task to just get the conversion right.                                                                                                            Test Qty
A 100
B '1000'
C 200
D '2000'
E 300
F '3000'
G 400
H '4000'
I 500
J '5000'

Comment: Thanks Cheng An, it worked, now that I found how to change str numbers to int numbers that can be added, do you know how to move them from the cell they are in as string, into another cell (combining the above process to convert it), so they can be added in the excel file

Comment: you can write the dataframe to the excel file with r  = open('file') and then r.write(dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

The worksheetfunction `=SUM(B2:B12)` will sum up both strings and numbers.

If you wish to convert the strings to numbers, loop through the range and multiply each value with 1. In VBA it would look like this: `Cell.Value = Val(Cell.Value) * 1`